# Shopify Liquid if statement to show

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create a liquid if statement to only run if product page == ?

```js
  {% if template contains 'products' and page.url == '/products/sky-dweller' %}
    <script>window.location.href = '/';</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Describe the problem, thank you

Comment: If you're on a product page, you won't have a `page` variable - that's only for the pages created at [your-store]/admin/pages. Instead, you could try checking `if product.handle == 'sky-dweller'`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation here](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/template#template-name) you can check if the template name is product.

```
{% if template.name == 'product' %}
  This will only appear on product pages.
{% endif %}
```